# How to define an array in my models using mysql sequelize | node.js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

This is the result what I need to store in DB :

sellers : [{'test1'},{'test2'},{'test3'}]

And this is my model:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      sellers: [
       {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
    ],
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
      defaultScope: {
        attributes: {
          exclude: ["password"],
        },
      },
      scopes: {
        withPassword: {
          attributes: {},
        },
      },
      indexes: [
        {
          unique: true,
          fields: ["email"],
        },
      ],
    }
  );

  return User;
};
```

And the error is :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Comment: This should be another model(table) called sellers and related to that model(table) above. The relation is one user to many sellers

Answer (score -1):

```
 sellers: [
   {
    type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
    allowNull: true,
  }
```

Comment: Also returns the same error

Answer (score -1):

You need to slightly change your schema definition as,

```
sellers: {
  type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.JSON),
  allowNull: true,
  defaultValue: [{}],
  get() {
    const data = this.getDataValue('sellers');
    const queryResponse = [];
    data.forEach(seller => {
      queryResponse.push(JSON.parse(seller));
    });
    return queryResponse;
  },
  set(seller) {
    return this.setDataValue('sellers', JSON.stringify(seller));
  }
},
```

Comment: Also returns the same error .. 

`
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[] DEFAULT , 
`
My sql version is "mysql  Ver 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))"

Comment: I think the defaultValue has to be ```[{}]```. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: First, Thanks for your interest ,

I try this and return `Error: Invalid value {}`